# wamp and mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I installed mongodb.I have wamp running(latest version), this comes with sqlbuddy any way to link this with the database? Any other aplication that can offer a visual interface for working with mongodb ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manage mongo databases with sqlbuddy. I would suggest you to look at [RockMongo](http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/rock_mongo).

**Edit**

RockMongo hasn't been supported in years, and isn't compatible with modern versions of MongoDB. There's an Open Source desktop client called [RoboMongo](http://robomongo.org/) that works on Windows, Linux, and Mac which might be a good fit.